# WinJS: Nested ListViews

Tags: listview, winjs

I have problem with nested ListViews in a Windows 8 Metro application. I get error:

```
Exception was thrown at line 5840, column 33 in 
ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: 
Unable to get property 'dataSource' of undefined or null reference
```

The code is:

```
<div id="color" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div>color</div>
</div>
<div id="row" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div 
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
            data-win-options="{ itemDataSource : colorsDataSource.dataSource, 
                    itemTemplate: select('#color')}">  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="basicListView" 
    data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
    data-win-options="{ itemDataSource : Data.rowsDataSource.dataSource, 
            itemTemplate: select('#row')}">  
</div>
```

The problematic line is:

```
data-win-options="{ itemDataSource : colorsDataSource.dataSource, 
                    itemTemplate: select('#color')}"
```

The problem is that at the moment when the data-win-options is being evaluated the colorsDataSource is somehow not accessible - not sure why, because the data structure Data is static and initialized before the UI is even parsed (before args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());).

For example when I try modify the **row** template to this:

```
<div id="row" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div data-win-bind="innerText: colorsDataSource.dataSource" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It outputs correctly [object Object]...

The javascript structure Data looks like this:

```
var rows = new WinJS.Binding.List([]);
model.rows.forEach(function (row) {
    rows.push({
       colorsDataSource : new WinJS.Binding.List(row.rowData.colors)
    });                
});
Data.rowsDataSource = rows;
```

**EDIT:**
Hm, I found the reason (processing of the attribute **data-win-options** in base.js):

```
var options;
var optionsAttribute = element.getAttribute("data-win-options");
if (optionsAttribute) {
    options = WinJS.UI.optionsParser(optionsAttribute, global, {
        select: createSelect(element)
    });
}
```

The options are evaluated in **global** context, that means there is no way how to get currently processed item (in my case the **row** item)...

Workaround is to create custom renderer (whole custom control). Which is partly described here http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/05/23/metro-dynamically-switching-templates-with-a-winjs-listview.aspx - see itemTemplateFunction

Answer (score 0):

Nested listviews basically don't work and aren't supported. You won't find an easy answer, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Tavares states, nested ListViews are not supported.

However, the *bigger* reason this doesn't work, is that you need to some how obtain the data itself on the next control (lets ignore that it's a list view for now).

You've tried to resolve this using the `data-win-options` attribute, which as you correctly pointed out only resolves to the global namespace.

There *is* a work around to this -- use a data binding.

Where you have:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
     data-win-options="{ itemDataSource : colorsDataSource.dataSource, 
     itemTemplate: select('#color')}">  
</div>
```

Remove the `itemsDataSource` from `data-win-options`, and move it to a data-win-bind:

```
<div  data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
      data-win-options="{ itemTemplate: select('#color')}"
      data-win-bind="winControl.itemDataSource: colorsDataSource.dataSource">  
</div>
```

This assumes that colorsDataSource is a property off the item that is being rendered. e.g. your row object.

To solve your nested problem, it looks like your "parent" listview could go away -- just create the elements dynamically based on your datasource.